# how to position hero image on a webpage

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have **5635x3757** jpg image which I want to position on my webpage[image: required image].
To achieve this I have loaded the image like this

```
<img alt="" class="zoom-image-head__abtbg" src="asset/img/about-page-bg.jpg" /
```

and the required image i have written CSS code like this

```
    .zoom-image-head__abtbg{
  position: absolute;
  height: 111vh;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  background-position: top;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80vw;
  object-position: 20vw
  
}
```

which makes the image like this [image: this pic shows the image affected by my code]
If I increase the image width it gets wider I want to image to be like this but to touch the right side of the page and also stay the same on the left side just like the required pic. anyone help, please. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin-right` or `padding-right` to the image in `vw`and see what is happening

Comment: it stays the same margin-right doesn't do anything and padding-right makes it to the left on increasing and when i decrease it. it stays the same

Comment: As i see in the image you attached, you want your image start from `about us` and end to `blog` menu item, right ??

Comment: Put your image inside parent element such as `div` and give the margin and padding to the div

Comment: when i try to put it inside the div it comes out of the div and isn't affected by the div at all

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? And the divs surrounding the image should not be `position:relative;`.

```
   .zoom-image-head__abtbg{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 5vw;      
      height: 111vh;
      width: 80vw;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: 20vw
    }
```

Comment: tried it. it just brought the image down nothing more

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .bg-img {
        background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832__480.jpg");
        background-position: top right;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 80%;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
      }
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="bg-img">
      
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).